# Retrieve multiple data with same name in one table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function search_review($input, $serviceName){
        $ipJson = json_encode($input);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('reviews');
        $this->db->where('reviewee_name', $input['reviewee_name']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        if (!empty($result)) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data['reviewer_id'] = $row->reviewer_id;
            $data['reviewee_name'] = $row->reviewee_name;
            $data['tournament_played_c_s'] = $row->tournament_played_c_s;
        }
            $data['message'] = 'Review details retrieved successfully.';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        } else {
            $data['message'] = 'Unable to retrieve review details.';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        }
        return $status;
    }
```

This is my code i can retrieve single row data with same name. eg reviewee_name="sangeetha" means i need to display  the details who are having name sangeetha. but now  single row data only iam getting what i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//don't overwrite the array values
function search_review($input, $serviceName){

    $data = array();

    $ipJson = json_encode($input);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('reviews');
    $this->db->where('reviewee_name', $input['reviewee_name']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    if (!empty($result)) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            //here you're overwriting the values
            $data[]['reviewer_id'] = $row->reviewer_id;
            $data[]['reviewee_name'] = $row->reviewee_name;
            $data[]['tournament_played_c_s'] = $row->tournament_played_c_s;
        }
        $data['message'] = 'Review details retrieved successfully.';
        $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
    } else {
        $data['message'] = 'Unable to retrieve review details.';
        $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: `<data>
      <_0>
         <reviewer_id>3</reviewer_id>
      </_0>
      <_1>
         <reviewee_name>deepi</reviewee_name>
      </_1>
      <_2>
         <tournament_played_c_s>chennai,TN</tournament_played_c_s>
      </_2>
      <_3>
         <reviewer_id>4</reviewer_id>
      </_3>
      <_4>
         <reviewee_name>deepi</reviewee_name>
      </_4>
      <_5>
         <tournament_played_c_s>karnataka,bangalore</tournament_played_c_s>
      </_5>
      <message>Review details retrieved successfully.</message>
   </data>`

Comment: tell me what is that delete your existing comments and add it or modify your question

Comment: if i need to get my output in separate array means what i need to do  sundar

Answer (score 0):

looking at you code.. i could see you are replacing the same key in data array.. so here is the problem ..

try this

```
..
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        $data[]['reviewer_id'] = $row->reviewer_id;
        $data[]['reviewee_name'] = $row->reviewee_name;
        $data[]['tournament_played_c_s'] = $row->tournament_played_c_s;
 }
...
```

this won't replace the key..however $data will have different structure (two dimensional array) so just be careful while displaying it..use `echo "<pre>";print_r($data);` to check the $data structure